# How to connect external codecs/filters to KMPlayer?

Tags: video, media-player

There is players that supports either DTS and AC3 or custom aspect ratio, I need both these features in one player. But it seem that there is no such player, but it is possible to use codecs/filters. Here is some info from quora, but can understand exactrly how to do it: https://www.quora.com/What-Android-video-player-supports-a-custom-aspect-ratio-and-MKV-with-DTS-and-AC3/answer/Lareina-Bronte?srid=qgmD